# Changed Status (Mysqli Fetch Array)

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to ask how did I change the status as I using fetch array result. Below is my link:

```html
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    
echo "<tr><td><font size='2'>' . $row['staff_name'] . '</td>
<td><a href="survey.php?staff_id=' . $row['staff_id'] . '"> '.$_SESSION['status1'].'</a></center></td></tr>';  

}  
echo '</table>';
```

Above is the code where it will diplay list of staff name. And each row will be link to survey.php to answer survey for each rows. But after I answer the survey from one of the rows, and redirect back to page, the status did change from 'Not complete' to 'Completed'. However, all rows are affected by status 'Completed'.

How do I select one row and answer the survey and the status change to 'Completed', then only I answer other rows that not yet been completed. TQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `$_SESSION['status1']` for all of the staff members.  Therefore, when that variable is set, it will look like all surveys are completed.

You may want to consider another way of doing this, however, such as using a MySQL table that stores whether or not a user has completed a survey, and load the status from there.

Comment: thanx. I will try to look further on my code. Thank you btw

Comment: @Daario if you really need to use sessions, set the name of the session to `survey_staff_id` or something unique.  However, the session will eventually expire, so the completed status will change.